# WordPress domain redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, plugins

Beginner question:
I need to perform a 301 redirect from one Wordpress site (domain), to another Wordpress domain, like this:
From:
http://mycompany.com
To:
http://mycompany.se

A problem is that I have no FTP credentials for my From-site. I can't reach the .htaccess file.

Is there a plugin to use? I have studied the Redirection plugin, but this one seems working on pages within the same domain only(?)

I guess I need to be careful, because if some plugin edits the .htaccess file and something breaks, I can't reach the file...
Thankful for any help!

Comment: Hello you dont need to be access on .htaccess use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-domain-changer/ than change your settings will be fix your problem

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whit [Redirection Plugin](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) you can redirect a url from old to new website.

[image]

You can create and manage redirects quickly and easily without needing Apache or Nginx knowledge. If your WordPress supports permalinks then you can use Redirection to redirect any URL.

There is full support for regular expressions so you can create redirect patterns to match any number of URLs.

The plugin can also be configured to monitor when post or page permalinks are changed and automatically create a redirect to the new URL.

Comment: Thank you Nick! I'll give it a try, I think it supports permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find multiple plugins to perform 301 redirection in wordpress,but if you want to edit .htaccess you can install the plugin called "WP htaccess control" https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/ .
Through this plugin you can edit the .hraccess file from admin side.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Ashish! so it's still possible to get at the .access file? Great, will have a look at that as well...